# Python sqlite3 recursive query for category tree structure

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around recursive queries and hoping someone can point me in right direction.

Here is some example data which represents a category structure of a website:

```
Code                      Label            Level  Parent Code

auto-moto                 Auto - Moto      1
autokinito                Car              2      auto-moto
car-aksesouar             Car accessories  3      autokinito
diakosmitika-aytokinitou  Car Decorations  4      car-aksesouar
katharistika-aytokinitou  Car Cleaners     4      car-aksesouar
keraies autokinhtou       Car Antennas     4      car-aksesouar
car-analosima             Car Reusables    3      autokinito
ladia-aytokinitou         Car Oils         4      car-analosima
lampes-aytokinitou        Car Lamps        4      car-analosima
```

I need to recursively look up and find the "Label" value attached to the level 1 and level 2 "ancestors" for each Code value in list, eg, look up parent_code for the code, then traverse to the parent above that, until you get to level 1.  For example, if you manually look through to find this for Code "diakosmitika-aytokinitou", "Auto - Moto" is the level 1 "Label" value I need, and "Car" is the level 2 "Label" value I need.

So far, I came up with this:

```
query3="WITH RECURSIVE parent(x) AS ("\
            "SELECT 'diakosmitika-aytokinitou' "\
             "   UNION ALL "\
            "SELECT categories.parent_code "\
            "FROM categories, parent "\
            "WHERE categories.code=parent.x AND categories.parent_code IS NOT NULL "\
        ")"\
        "SELECT * FROM parent;"
```

which gives me this output as result set:

```
(u'diakosmitika-aytokinitou',)
(u'car-aksesouar',)
(u'autokinito',)
(u'auto-moto',)
(u'',)
```

So, I got as far as getting all the ancestors.  I can't seem to figure out how to take this to the next step and get what I want, without taking my results and then looping through with another query to find the ones with parent_code of 1 and 2...hoping to find a more elegant way, because my real data is much larger!    Thanks!

PS: Using Python 2.7 and sqlite3

Comment: You already *are* using another query to loop through the result (at the bottom). Just add the level to the CTE.

Comment: Thanks, CL.  I stabbed at this for a while and came up with below code, which just reproduced my original data over and over     `query3="WITH RECURSIVE cte AS ("\
            "SELECT  code , parent_code,  label, level FROM categories"\
             "   UNION ALL "\
            "SELECT  categories.code, categories.parent_code, categories.label, categories.level "\
            "FROM categories, cte "\
            "WHERE categories.code=cte.code AND   categories.parent_code IS NOT NULL  "\
        ")"\
        "SELECT * FROM cte  WHERE code='diakosmitika-aytokinitou' LIMIT 100;"
`

Answer (score 0):

Just add the information you need to the CTE:

```
query = """WITH RECURSIVE parents AS (
             SELECT label, level, parent_code
             FROM categories
             WHERE code = 'diakosmitika-aytokinitou'

             UNION ALL

             SELECT c.label, c.level, c.parent_code
             FROM categories c
             JOIN parents p ON c.code = p.parent_code
           )
           SELECT label
           FROM parents
           WHERE level BETWEEN 1 AND 2
           ORDER BY level"""
```

Comment: Thanks, CL. That got me close].   I wanted the "leaf code" & level too, so: `query4 = """WITH RECURSIVE parents AS (
             SELECT  label, level, parent_code
             FROM categories
             WHERE code = 'diakosmitika-aytokinitou'

             UNION ALL

             SELECT  c.label, c.level, c.parent_code
             FROM categories c
             JOIN parents p ON c.code = p.parent_code
           )
           SELECT CAST ('diakosmitika-aytokinitou' as TEXT),label,level
           FROM parents
           WHERE level BETWEEN 1 AND 2
           ORDER BY level"""`

Comment: So, now when I try to loop through all categories to get these results for each code, the loop seems to stop at the first one,even thought I know there are many category codes stored.   `querycat="SELECT * FROM categories"
catresult=crsr.execute(querycat)
for c in catresult:
     ..do the recursive query...   
     for i in result:
            print(i) #really, I will want to insert it somewhere else. `

Comment: The problem is likely to be in the code you have not shown. And that is a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: I got it working by putting the "code I haven't shown" into a function and calling the function from the loop.  It's messy, but gets what I need done.  Thanks!